# how could I read and use the text file values (comma separated or line separated) in an awk command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sh

I have an awk command to filtering the rows using column 2.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = FS;} {if ($2=="ABC" || $2=="DEF" || $2=="PQR" || $2=="XYZ") print}' $1  >> $1tmp
```

Can I get the logic so that i can read values (ABC,DEF,XYZ) using a text file and pass it in awk.

Inputfile.csv

```
1,ABC,100
2,XYZ,200
3,MNO,100
4,PQR,100
5,EFG,100
6,QWE,100
7,DEF,200
```

Output should be like

```
1,ABC,100
2,XYZ,200
4,PQR,100
7,DEF,200
```

value.txt file contains

```
ABC
PQR
DEF
XYZ
```

There are multiple ways i tried to achieve this

```
filename = value.txt
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = FS;} {if ($2=="$line") print}' Inputfile.csv
done < $filename
```

but didn't work, and i think if it work some how then may take lot much time to process large data.

Another approach

```
filename = value.txt
ind=0
while read line ; do
MYARRAY[$ind]=$line
index=$(($ind+1))
done < $filename
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = FS;} {if ($2== ${MYARRAY[@]})
```

but here the problem is MyArray print the value as a string (ABC PQR XYZ....) which does not match the if condition in awk

Comment: Amit singh, you have to post sample(s) of input and sample of output in your post along with your efforts too, let us know then.

Comment: You can pass a variable to `awk` this is not a problem! Also it might be easier to regroup all the strings for comparison to one variable that you can pass to `awk` as a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, then given a file `variables.txt` containing

```
ABC
DEF
PQR
XYZ
```

And an input file `data.txt` containing

```
1|ABC
2|nope
3|asdkl
4|PQR
5|stuff
6|DEF
7|XYZ
```

You could use

```
awk -F '|' 'NR == FNR { vars[$1]; next } $2 in vars' variables.txt data.txt
```

to obtain

```
1|ABC
4|PQR
6|DEF
7|XYZ
```

This works as follows:

```
NR == FNR {   # When processing the first file (overall record number equal to
              # record number within the file)
  vars[$1]    # remember that $1 was seen
  next        # and process the next record
}
$2 in vars    # when processing the second file: filter for lines where
              # $2 is one of those remembered tokens.
```